# Skip just some test in Maven

Tags: maven, junit

I have many profiles in maven for different environments  and I want to skip some tests with some of those profiles. Is it possible to skip some test classes? I've been looking for that and only found the property `skipTests`, but it skips all the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You basically have two options:

- use -Dtest=!testToExclude,!test2ToExclude (these tests need noot to be qualified).
  See [Surefire-Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test):

> Specify this parameter to run individual tests by file name, overriding the `includes/excludes` parameters. Each pattern you specify here will be used to create an include pattern formatted like `**/${test}.java`, so you can just type "`-Dtest=MyTest`" to run a single test called "`foo/MyTest.java`". The test patterns prefixed with a ! will be excluded.
>   This parameter overrides the `includes/excludes` parameters, and the TestNG suiteXmlFiles parameter. Since 2.7.3, you can execute a limited number of methods in the test by adding `#myMethod` or `#my*ethod`. For example, "`-Dtest=MyTest#myMethod`". This is supported for junit 4.x and testNg.

- You could also use the excludeFile parameter if you want to exclude many tests.

**Update:**

This answer assumes you want to dynamically exclude tests from the command line. If you want your tests always to be excluded in specific profiles, Aleksandr's anwswer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) to exclude some tests based on ant-style path expression or regular expression.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.17</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/SomeTest.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In order to use regular expression the syntax is `%regex[expr]` where expr is the actual expression. Also note that regex matches are done over `.class` files and not `.java` files.